How are there $2^n$ $n$-variable parity functions?
Source: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/boolean-analysis/lecture2.pdf
Context: Linearity testing of boolean functions is being discussed, and they just introduced parity functions which I didn't know about.
In the pdf, it says:

as if there are $2^n$ parity functions.
UPDATED QUESTION: What does it mean for $\chi_S$ to be a parity function on a set $S$?
My initial interpretation of this statement was that the function should return $1$ if an odd number of elements in $S$ are $1$ in the input, and $0$ otherwise. That would have been good, except it's probably wrong because the pdf says that they are arranging the entries in the vector based on lexicographic order of the inputs. In that case, $\chi_{\{1\}}$ should have been $[0,0,...,0,1,1,...,1]$.
Please help.

It's clarified right there in the last sentence: $\chi_S$ is parity on the coordinates in the set $S$, which is an arbitrary subset of $[n]$, and there are $2^n$ such subsets.

@QiaochuYuan I read that, but I didn't understand what it means -- what does it mean for $\chi_S$ to be a parity function ON a set $S$?
My initial interpretation of this statement was that the function should return $1$ if an odd number of elements in $S$ are $1$, and $0$ otherwise. That would have been good, except it's probably wrong because the pdf says that they are arranging the entries in the vector based on lexicographic order of the inputs. In that case, $\chi_{{1}}$ should have been $[0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1, ..., 1]$.

It means it calculates the parity function (in the sense that Wikipedia means it) but only for the bits corresponding to the subset $S$; explicitly this means $\chi_S(x) = \sum_{i \in S} x_i$ where by addition I mean XOR. I don't understand the choice of ordering being used in the pdf but I think "parity on the coordinates in set $S$" is pretty unambiguous.

Oh ok. Maybe it was a mistake then, and the entries of the parity vectors shown were supposed to be ordered lexicographically.
If anyone has any insight, please let me know -- otherwise I will just assume that it was a mistake on the writer's end.

${1}$ indicates the Least Significant bit so it goes $0101\cdots$. From there you can deduce the rest. Regardless of the number of variables the parity of the full set $[n]$ starts $0110$ since only ${1,2}$ are active in the first 4 positions. There is nothing wrong with the notes
